# How to override inline styles using CSS?

Tags: html, css, api

I'm trying to override an inline style set by a 3rd party API,
the element in question

```
<li class="BrainhubCarouselItem BrainhubCarouselItem--active" 
style="padding-right: 25px; padding-left: 25px; width: 225px; 
max-width: 225px; min-width: 225px;"/>
```

I have tried selecting the element like so

```
li.BrainHubCarouselItem.BrainHubCarouselItem--active {
  padding-left: 3px !important;
  padding-right: 3px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}
```

However none of the styling is taking place

Comment: inline style has the highest priority. what you can do it add inline style or replace using javascript

Comment: You can only replace the inline css throught jquery or js by writing that css using !important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change BrainHubCarouselItem to BrainhubCarouselItem  (H to h)

```
li.BrainhubCarouselItem.BrainHubCarouselItem--active { .... }
```

So your css would look like this

```
li.BrainhubCarouselItem.BrainhubCarouselItem--active {
  padding-left: 3px !important;
  padding-right: 3px !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}
```